# Any trick to speed up Android 4.0 emulator?

Tags: android-emulator, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have rather strong dual core PC with 6GB RAM and yet Android 4.0 and 4.03 emulators are very, very slow.

Is there any trick to speed up this emulator or I would have to buy a new i5/i7 processor (like suggested in some other post)?

I am asking this as we've managed to speed up emulators in the past so there's got to be some trick to make it faster (both booting and working).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to scale screen size of your emulator to a smaller size.

For examples:

Screen size (in): 3 or 4

Monitor dpi: 160

Comment: WOW, this really helps! Have you managed to find a solution for the native resolution (hdpi, LArge screen)? This one is very slow